# CMD: doesn't recognize the path

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i have created a simple batch, that should get the value from the input, and act according to the choice:

```
set CA="C:\A\"
set CB="C:\B\"
set SRV="server\"
set /p choice=Insert choice (A/B):
if %choice%== A cd /d %CA%%SRV% & start ""  "batch.bat" 
if %choice%== B cd /d %CB%%SRV% & start ""  "batch.bat"
```

In the script the first choice works as expected, whereas the second one throws: "The system cannot find the path specified".
The path is correct and the file is there. Directly from CMD the single command works fine. What am i doing wrong in the script?

Comment: You've got a typo. `set CB=:C:\B\"` should be `set CB="C:\B\"`

Comment: oh thanks. it is just a typo here. in real set is done correctly.

Comment: Well, that was the only thing I saw wrong with your code. Perhaps the error is coming from batch.bat?

Comment: I would certainly suggest removing the spaces after the `==` and possibly include a case insensitive option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with your structure, would the following work for you?

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "CA=C:\A\"
Set "CB=C:\B\"
Set "SRV=server\"
Set /P "choice=Insert choice (A/B): "
If /I "%choice%"=="A" If Exist "%CA%%SRV%batch.bat" Start "" /D"%CA%%SRV%" "batch.bat"
If /I "%choice%"=="B" If Exist "%CB%%SRV%batch.bat" Start "" /D"%CB%%SRV%" "batch.bat"
Pause
```

Comment: It works with validation. Thanks. Just wonder why it couldn't detect the file for the second IF